# My program loop won't sent give a correct output

Tags: loops, output

I am trying to create a loop that finds how long it would take for "MP" to be higher than "AP". However, when I start the program it tells me "Mexico's population will exceed in 121Years." until I force end the program. Do you know where I went wrong?

```
public class Population
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int Mexico = 121;
        int America = 315;
        int MYear = (101/100); 
        int AYear = (15/100);
        int MP = (Mexico * MYear);
        int AP = (America * MYear);
        while (MP <= AP) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Mexico's population will exceed in " + MP + "Years."); 

        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You're not changing any values in the loop, why would you expect it to stop?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning how to code. I dont understand what you mean. How do i make it so the values change?

Comment: @CorruptedWizard you need to update the values of `MP` and `AP` in the loop. Otherwise the variables are effectively static. `int MP = (Mexico * MYear)` sets the value to that each time in the loop; neither `Mexico` or `MYear` change, so `MP` will never change.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @jmoerdyk. My teacher refuses to help as insists he taut it even though he hasn't. So if you can help it would be amazing